# Ejecutar javascript al terminar una llamada a webapi

Tags: angularjs, webapi

obtengo un listado de objetos de una webapi con visual studio, y la tomo asi:

```
$http.post('/sistema/api/Persona/Search', param).then(function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                return genericSuccess(data);
            })

function genericSuccess(data) {            
            $scope.listadoPersonas = data.data;
});
```

A ese listado lu uso en la vista y con un ng-repeat lo imprimo en una tabla, lo que necesito es una vez ejecutado el ng-repeat, a ese listado aplicarle una funcion javascript, pero siempre me da error porque cuando quiero apñlicale la funcion javascript recorriendo por los id de los div que voy generadno, me dice que el listado $scope.listadpPersonas no existe.
Ya intente con

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
```

Pero nada, como puedo hacer? tengo que hacer una promesa y ejecutarla al terminar? como hago esto?

gracias

Comment: mire esto como guía: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001567/8933039

Comment: Gracias, intente hacerlo de esa forma, llamando a una funcion pasada por parámetro, pero al final lo resolvi con este link, al finalizar el ng-repeat, modificando la directiva
https://code.i-harness.com/es/q/cd8d99
Muchas gracias